# DELETE method .NET WebAPI does not work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, wcf-web-api

I've seen tons of posts about this, but the DELETE method of my new WebAPI simply does not work and returns a 404, using Windows 7 32-bit, IIS 7.5.

I've tried

- Uninstalling WebDAV
- Adding PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS to the ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 handler (and 32bit/64bit handlers).
- Allowing all modules to run.

All to no avail and all return 404. If I change the DELETE type to a GET, then the service runs the GET command perfectly fine.

Anyone with any other ideas about this? It's driving me crazy.

EDIT:

I'm calling the DELETE method like this (mediator is a wrapper around the jQuery call):

```
mediator.publish("AjaxCall", {
                url: "/api/files/" + $(a.currentTarget).data("fileid"),
                type: "DELETE",
                }
            });
```

And WebAPI:

```
// DELETE api/<controller>/5
// [HttpDelete] - Tried this too
public void Delete(int fileId)
{
     Files.DeleteFile(fileId);
}
```

And relevant web.config:

```
<handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
```

Comment: How are you calling the `DELETE` method - what's the client side of this setup?

Comment: (The issue I'm thinking about is whether the request is being treated as a Cross Origin request - have you tried implementing `OPTIONS` and seeing whether that gets hit first?)

Comment: OPTIONS is coming up with 'Method not allowed' - using both JSON and JSONP as the dataType. JSON/JSONP/XML for DELETE is still 404.

Comment: Is your app pool running in "Integrated" managed pipeline mode? (your preCondition is preCondition="integratedMode")... may be worth a cheeky aspnet_regiis -ir in command prompt to ensure IIS is properly set up.

Comment: Apparently my system has no aspnet_regiis.exe on there whatsoever, even when repairing .NET 4.5... the story continues...

Comment: Now I have regiis, I ran that command and still got nothing to work. I'm now running the service under full IIS and still no luck with it - pretty much out of options now.

Comment: I meant to implement an `Options` method in your Server API, but continue to send the `Delete` method. If you find your `Options` method being invoked first, it would indicate that the browser thinks that this is a Cross Origin request.

Comment: @thedixon If you are actually using IIS Express... then this question answered by Mark S should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-vs2012rc-iis-8 (Add PUT and DELETE verbs into %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config)

Comment: For a 404, it sounds like it can't find the route. Check the raw response; is it IIS or ASP.NET looking response? I do have a config you can use, but not at work right now. Something like:

`<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" runManagedModulesForWebDavRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>`

You could try making the API call as simple as possible:

[HttpDelete, Route("api/test")]
public void Delete(int fileId) { throw new NotImplementedException();}

Comment: Sorry that should be something like:

[HttpDelete, Route("api/test")]
public void Delete() { throw new NotImplementedException();}

Answer (score 2):

The Solution is to add PUT & DELETE verb in correct applicationHost.config file.

For IIS :

Go to lcation: C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config
and edit the applicationHost.config file as:

```
 <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

For IIS EXPRESS GO TO : 
%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\
and do the same in applicationHost.config file.

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting under "Default Web Site" ?
If yes then try hosting it separately on a different port.

I have the same issue with PUT and DELETE and the workaround was successful.

Comment: I'm actually running under IIS Express. Having numerous security issues with trying to run the service under general IIS.

Comment: @thedixon your question stated IIS 7.5... but if you are actually using IIS Express... then this question answered by Mark S should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-vs2012rc-iis-8 (Add PUT and DELETE verbs into %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config)

Answer (score 0):

If You are using attribute routing, update *AcceptVerbs* with DELETE and PUT methods like this :

```
[Route("{fileId:int}")]
[AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
public void Delete(int fileId)
{
   Files.DeleteFile(fileId);
}
```

Also if you are writing *fileId* as parameter name then dont forget to update the webAPI route config to *api/files/{fileId}*

And also use *AcceptVerbs* attribute for GET and PUT as well because these three have same URL structure to call their methods. Also update the Controller with RoutePrefix as below:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/files")]
public class FileController : ApiController
{
}
```