# WebAPI OData Service WCF DataService Client DELETE

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, wcf-data-services

I implemented a WebAPI Odata V3 endpoint.  I then used the WCF Data Services client in Silverlight to access the Odata endpoint.  The GET, and the updates work great.  However, when I try to submit a delete I see using Fiddler that the client is sending a POST and X-HTTP-Method: DELETE instead of a DELETE.

According to the documentation, the default behavior should be a DELETE request, but with a override of using the .UsePostTunneling = true; on the data service client to send the extension method.  When I try to set UsePostTunneling = false; the authentication (Negotiate) fails making GETS fail as well.

Using Fiddler I can submit a DELETE request and it executes correctly, so it seems like the server works correctly.

What would cause the client to send a POST instead of a DELETE by default?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DELETE method .NET WebAPI does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313978/delete-method-net-webapi-does-not-work)

Comment: Its because IIS doesn't by default let you use "custom" HTTP verbs like Delete. The default ones are just GET and POST.

Comment: I'll try that.  However, the DELETE method does work.  The problem is the client is sending the request as a POST not a DELETE

Comment: Adding the verbs to the applicationHost.config file had no affect.  The client still sent the request as a POST rather than a DELETE.

Comment: I've done some further research.  In the WCF Client, the SendingRequest2 event does show a DELETE request is being created.  So it is being changed to a POST event somewhere down the line.  The Intelisense states that it could be change by the handler?  Is there a way to control the handler?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find a way to change the behavior of the client.  However, I did solve my problem.  What I did was override the handler on the server side, and if the request was a POST with the x-HTTP-Method:Delete in the header I changed it to a DELETE request.  This is detailed here:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPUTOrDELETENotAllowedUseXHTTPMethodOverrideForYourRESTServiceWithASPNETWebAPI.aspx