# Web API Delete Method not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Calling a DELETE method Web API is not reaching the server. After searching all over the web for similar issues non have worked for me.
Below is a brief of my code across my solution.

**Web API:**

```
    [AuthorizeService]
    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(Int32 id)
    {
        String username = User.Identity.Name;
        this._clientDataManager.DeleteRestaurant(id,username);

        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

**Ajax Call:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'localhost:53378/api/RestaurantWebAPI/1135',
    type: "DELETE",
    statusCode: {
        200: function (data) {
            //success
        }
    }, beforeSend: setHeader
});
```

**Web.Config:**

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

</system.webServer>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you remove AuthorizeService attribute for a trial and see if its reachable?

Comment: @ancdev are you sure that the `AuthorizeService` aspect or filter isn't preventing your operation call?

Comment: My problem is that the response is 404 Not Found. This Attribute performs a simple authentication nothing fancy there.

Comment: @ancdev and the remaining HTTP methods of this controller are working fine? right? I mean have u tried GET method there?

Comment: GET, POST, PUT Works perfectly

Comment: Strange... 404 means routing not able to match

Comment: Check out this, in case you are missing 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-vs2012rc-iis-8

Comment: Do u have WebDav module installed? if so, remove it and try again.https://gist.github.com/3524198

Answer (score -5):

Ok got it to work but somehow the solution confused me a bit.
First the solution, ended up adding the below to the WebApiConfig file:

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "DeleteApi",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/Delete/{id}",
       defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Now, isn't this a feature in MVC 4 Web API for the request to be routed directly to the delete method when the type of the request is set to "DELETE"? Any clarifications on this matter is highly appriciated.