# What is correct format for WCF PUT request?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, put

I'm struggling sending a PUT request to WCF in format that it expects.  I was thinking I could send it much like a GET with a QueryString, but that just kicked back errors.

```
    //Put operation
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "?tid={transcriptId}&qId={quizId}&cid={choice}&mid={mbox}&status={status}", Method = "PUT", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    vTranscript UpdateTranscript(string transcriptId, string quizId, string choice, string mbox, string status);
```

I also tried sending as XML and JSON file using CURL, but the values from those files weren't picked up by the service (values were null).

```
[DataContract]
public class vTranscript
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool validUser;
    [DataMember]
    public bool correctAnswer;
    [DataMember]
    public bool recorded;
  }
```

I'm assuming that my vTranscript does *not* have to match the parameters I pass in, though I even tried that.

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your parameters are posted you just need the following: (note that the posted names must match the method parameter names)

```
//Put operation
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
vTranscript UpdateTranscript(string transcriptId, string quizId, string choice, string mbox, string status);
```

UriTemplate is to define parameters that are embedded in the url itself.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  That worked, however now I'm getting "405 Method Not Allowed".  This seems to have a lot of possible causes when I google for the error message.  I'm running everything from within VS2010 so I doubt if it has to do with the cross domain issue I keep seeing.

Comment: The PUT and DELETE verbs are disabled by default.  This thread (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10907343/2711582) provides information on how to enable them.  A workaround on the client side is to do a POST and add the X-HTTP-Method-Override header to specify the actual verb.

Comment: After working on this some more, I was able to solve this.  I was wrapping my JSON as a JSON array, and not as a simple JSON string.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the bodystyle as below.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was also helpful.