# ASP.NET MVC HTTP Post/Delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-delete

I have a ASP.NET MVC app.
I have single function pattern which will be called both with HTTP POST and HTTP DELETE.

Although Post is called, Delete is never called. I confirmed that the IIS accepts HTTP Delete. Any comments?

Route and Controllers:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "RegisterCard",
            routeTemplate: "{version}/cards/{cardID}",
            defaults: new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "

           routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "UnregisterCard",
           routeTemplate: "{version}/cards/{cardID}",
           defaults: new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "Delete" });                




    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string version, string cardID);
    {
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Delete(string version, string cardID);
    {
    }
```

Comment: Which browser(s) are you using? IE 8 and 9 don't do AJAX DELETE/PUT very well. Try adding a "X-HTTP-Method-Override: Delete" header in the request and using POST. Does that trigger the action?

Comment: Check this answer and go through your config files

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Answer (score 1):

From the code above, i think any url with pattern `{version}/cards/{cardID}` will be handled by "RegisterCard" route no matter what the verb is(Post/Delete). For "Delete", "RegisterCard" route will be chosen, then when `[HttpPost]` action selector comes into play, it will result in a 404 error. If you are experiencing 404 for "Delete", you might

**ONE**
Add constraint to routes

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "RegisterCard",
    routeTemplate: "{version}/cards/{cardID}",
    defaults: new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "Post"},
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new[] { "post" }) }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "UnregisterCard",
    routeTemplate: "{version}/cards/{cardID}",
    defaults: new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "Delete" },
    constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new[] { "delete" }) }
);
```

**OR** Make a single route merging them together with a single `ActionName`

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Card",
    routeTemplate: "{version}/cards/{cardID}",
    defaults: new { Controller = "MyController", Action = "HandleCard"}
);

[ActionName("HandleCard")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string version, string cardID);
{
}

[ActionName("HandleCard")]
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Delete(string version, string cardID);
{
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that HTTP supports delete. Regardless, Just use post for your delete action. As long as you're not useing GET for a DELETE action, you're good. Here's some reference...

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-details-and-delete-methods