# Delete Action methods of Web API did not get trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller in my project, as follows

```
public class EmployeeController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IEmployeeRepository repository = new EmployeeRepository();
    // GET api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public object Get()
    {
        var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
        var data = repository.GetAll().ToList();
        return new { Items = data, Count = data.Count() };
    }

    public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        Employee emp = repository.Get(id);
        if (emp == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return emp;
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public HttpResponseMessage PostEmployee(Employee emp)
    {
        emp = repository.Add(emp);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse<Employee>(HttpStatusCode.Created, emp);

        string uri = Url.Link("Employee", new { id = emp.EmployeeID });
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(uri);
        return response;
    }
     [HttpPut]
    // PUT api/<controller>
    public void PutEmployee(Employee emp)
    {

        if (!repository.Update(emp))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

    }
    [HttpDelete]
     public void DeleteEmployee(int id)
    {
        Employee emp = repository.Get(id);
        if (emp == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        repository.Remove(id);
    }
}
```

For me, get and post method getting triggered correctly

But, Delete Method is not getting triggered.

and my Webapicongif.cs

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Employee",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();
    }
```

and the global.cs file as follows

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);



    }
```

once i did the delete to the Employee

```
General:

Request URL:http://localhost:63187/api/Employee/2
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:404 Not Found
Remote Address:[::1]:63187
```

Response Headers

```
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:204
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 30 Mar 2017 12:00:21 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?RDpcU2FtcGxlXE1WQ1xEYXRhTWFuYWdlclxBZGFwdG9yc1xTYW1wbGVcYXBpXEVtcGxveWVlXDI=?=
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
DataServiceVersion:2.0
Host:localhost:63187
MaxDataServiceVersion:2.0
Origin:http://localhost:63187
Referer:http://localhost:63187/CRUDRemote/Remove
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Request Payload

```
2
```

my ajax request will as below

```
beforeSend:function (),
contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
data:"2",
error:function (e),
success:function (),
type:"DELETE",
url:"/api/Employee/2",
```

Where i committing my mistake

Comment: take a look here and see if it can fix your issues
[same issue maybe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19708776/asp-net-mvc-http-post-delete)

Comment: From where you are calling the api, MVC application or Ajax request?

Comment: Could it be the webserver hosting the application not supporting the method?

Comment: Please specify the server in which your service is hosted. IIS? Self host?

Comment: Hi Sulay, I have called from Ajax request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last  i found the issue, i have done the mistake in Global.cs and WebApiConfig

Updated Global.cs filed

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

        //GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);


    //    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
```

and WebApiConfig

```
     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                        name: "Employee",
                        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                    );
        //config.EnableQuerySupport();
    }
```

Now, the Delete action updated triggered.

Answer (score 0):

In the new WebAPI project hosted under IIS, PUT and DELETE methods return 404 errors out of the box. `applicationhost.config` of IIS has to be edited before you use them.

> %userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config

Search for

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

and replace it by

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

and in addition to this as this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8) suggests, you have to comment out the following lines in the same file.

```
<add name="WebDAVModule" image="%IIS_BIN%\webdav.dll" />
<add name="WebDAVModule" /> 
<add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="PROPFIND,PROPPATCH,MKCOL,PUT,COPY,DELETE,MOVE,LOCK,UNLOCK" modules="WebDAVModule" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For me adding the following in web.config worked all the time.By default delete is not allowed when using WebAPI on remote server.

```
   <system.webServer>
    <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV" />
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"
    path="*."
    verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT"
    type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```