# ASP.NET MVC API PUT getting 404 error

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, http-status-code-404, restful-url

I have a .NET MVC RESTful API that works fine for GET and POST, but returns 404 for PUT requests:

```
[Authorize]
public class TasksController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/tasks
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all users tasks.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Task Object (JSON serialised)</returns>
    public IEnumerable<Task> Get()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        ...

        return tasks;

    }

    // GET api/tasks/5
    public Task Get(Int64 id)
    {
        Task thisTask = new Task();

        ...

        return thisTask;
    }

    // POST api/tasks
    public void Post(Task item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        ...
    }

    // PUT api/tasks/5
    public void Put(Int64 id, Task item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        } 

        ...
    }

    // DELETE api/tasks/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    // PUT, GET, POST, DELETE api/tasks...
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public HttpResponseMessage Options()
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        return response;
    }

}
```

Any idea why it wouldn't be picking up the PUT?  (Even OPTIONS works fine)

Routing:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // CORS Enabled
        //var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("localhost", "*", "*");
        //config.EnableCors(cors);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

Web.Config:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Authorization, Content-Type" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Addendum** It looks like the speed at which it is coming back is instant, even after a recompile, So I'm guessing it's not even getting to the application, so must be a configuration issue.

Comment: What's the `PUT` request look like that you're sending?

Comment: Not sure what you you mean?  I'm using Fiddler to test and it looks the same as the GET (api/tasks/17) except with a payload which I've copied from the GET call.

Comment: Sounds like PUT is not enabled in your webserver, take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Comment: What's the routing configuration? Right now `api/tasks/17` is going to throw a `404` on `PUT` because there is no matching signature.

Comment: Have added routing from WebApiConfig

Comment: Hakan, It works for other code that I have running on other ports on the same IIS, so not sure its a server config issue

Comment: You can configure this in the web.config system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders.

Comment: Like this:  `<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. So turns out it was due to having this commented out:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

...in the web.config, which I originally did to be able to use shared hosting.  Do'h!