# Adding handlers to IIS8

Tags: iis-8

I have IIS8 (complete, not Express) on Win8. I'm trying to make the PUT verb to work on IIS. In fact, my question would be exactly this: [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)

However, the highest voted answer (provided by the asker himself) doesn't help me because I just don't have the "ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" handler. It is simply missing, along with a host of other handlers, that I've have seen in screenshots from similar posts. My only three handlers (that show up on the Handler Mappings dialog of IIS management console at the server level) are: OPTIONSVerbHandler TRACEVerbHandler and StaticFile.

However much I've tried to find a way to add the "ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" handler, I've been unable to do it. I tried even to copy into %systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\
applicationHost.config the <add> element (within <handlers>) that the author of the referenced post used to solve the problem: <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />. But to no avail.

I know this is a very noob question (I'm new to IIS), but just have not been able to find an answer in the documentation. May I get a hand, pls?