# WebApi cannot get PUT to work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Im testing a webapi web service on my local machine. I cant get my PUT to work. I have the following response from the service:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET,POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcSHZhcnJlZ2FhcmRcRG9jdW1lbnRzXERyb3Bib3hcR3JlZW5XZWJcS3VuZGVyXE1hZHMgTW9nZW5zaMO4alxETEZcRExGU2VydmljZVxETEZTZXJ2aWNlXGFwaVxhY3Rpb25wbGFuYWN0aW9u?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Date: Tue, 24 Jun 2014 06:55:02 GMT
Content-Length: 72

{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}
```

I have added the CORS NuGet package and has the following setup:

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and service
            //enable cross origin requests (CORS)
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{secondid}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, secondid=RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            //configures to return json if the request accepts text/html
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }
    }
```

My web.config looks like this (its bits and pieces i found around SO):

```
 <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />

      <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="/security/*" verb="GET,POST, PUT, DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
      <add name="SettingsHandler" path="/api/settings/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
      <add name="SendHandler" path="/send/*" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*." type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

It seems that it does not allow me to send PUT, but only GET and POST. I cant figure out how to enable the PUT command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)

Comment: are you running your AppPool in integrated mode or classic mode IIS?

Comment: Running on development server in VS2013

Comment: Yeah that related post did the trick, editing the applicationhost.config did it. Im so happy that im at my own IIS and not at a ISP where I cant control the applicationhost.config. Any idea on what to do if thats the case?

Comment: Closed, duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Comment: not sure, but we have it running without that change. Perhaps you could try removing the WebDAV handler too: <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />... and <modules   runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">