# How to enable DELETE, PUT for PHP app at IIS?

Tags: php, http, iis, azure-web-app-service, cleardb

Although `DELETE` request works successfully locally, it does not work when I deploy my app to MS Azure.

Here is what I get in console when try to delete a record:

```
DELETE http://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/api/subjects/1 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

My app uses `mySQL` at `cleardb`

How to fix such a problem?

**EDIT**

My app is a PHP 5.5 app, here is what I tried to do in `web.config` to enable DELETE and PUT, but it didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs applyToWebDAV="false">
          <add verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" allowed="true" />
        </verbs>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

         <handlers>
<remove name="PHP55_via_FastCGI" />
  <add name="PHP55_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET, PUT, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, MKCOL, COPY, MOVE, LOCK, UNLOCK" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />

              <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
              <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
              <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
              <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS,XYZ" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
            </handlers>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: mind the spaces between GET, PUT, etc. in the "PHP55_via_FastCGI" handler definition - in my case it was the blocking factor - there should be no spaces

Answer (score 2):

I think PUT and DELETE are disabled in WebApi / IIS8 by default, which is what it looks like you are using. Quite a bit of discussion on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8).

Comment: please check the EDIT above

Comment: Ah sorry, I don't know about PHP web service configuration, I thought you where using WebApi.

Answer (score 2):

We need to add a bit of configuration in Web.Config file as explained here.

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2012/12/07/Configuring-IIS-verbs-for-ASPNET-Web-API-on-Windows-Azure-Websites-and-elsewhere.aspx

Comment: please check the EDIT above

Comment: This link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

As I know simply go to IIS user interface, then request filtering, then HTTP verbs. finally add a new allow rule to the wanted verbs