# Rest not allowing PUT in IIS 8.5 : error 405

Tags: c#, rest, iis, http-status-code-405

I have a restfull web service in .Net. When we tested the PUT in a PC with windows 7 and IIS 7 it works fine.

When we tested the web service in a PC with windows 8 and IIS 8.5 we get a 405 status code. This is the result from Fiddler

[image]

**Edit**
This is the applicationHost.config part regarding `ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated`. I don't have an ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated

[image]

I assume this is a IIS issue, anyone knows how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the PUT verb in your ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0 list.  Make the following change your applicationhost.config file for your IIS instance.

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,OPTIONS,TRACE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```

You will also want to add any other verbs you might be allowing like DELETE.

See: [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)

Comment: where should be that file? I have 4 files in that PC with named applicationhost.config

Comment: It depends on your configuration but by default it's located in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config

Comment: found it, there is an ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0, changed that and same result.

Comment: You can also see the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Answer (score 2):

It mainly happens due to WebDAV installation to IIS Server.

Just add the following XML block in your `web.config` file

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```