# 405 Method not allowed error in angularjs http Post request with IIS 8.5

Tags: php, angularjs, windows, vps, iis-8.5

I m getting "405 Method Not Allowed" error for my angularjs application running on PHP over iis 8.5

These are my header request...

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
```

What i can see is that post is missing in "Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE"

Can any one guide me how to enable POST request in IIS 8.5.

[image: Chrome screen shot]

[image]

SOLVED

```
i finally solve this.... I guess the issue was in MY URL - api/login which is called in POST... i changes that URL with api/login/checklogin.php and executed POST request.... it works.......

SUPER THANKS TO LIN for his guidance and 
http://stackoverflow.com always gives you the best.... THANKS ALL..
```

Comment: This is not a issue depending on your cors setup. CORS doesnt effect the http status code.

Comment: how to correct it... i tried every method on IIS 8.5 but  NO success till now... do you have any helpful link to share..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CORS do not effect the HTTP Status code > HTTP status codes effect cors**. Taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835088/rest-not-allowing-put-in-iis-8-5-error-405) answer you should allow all the HTTP-Request types in IIS 
you need.

#### For  IIS 8.x try:

You could follow up [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications) or make the following change in your `applicationhost.config`file for your instance:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Also ensure you removed WebDAV module from `web.config` (if installed and enabled):

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: i cannot see "WebDAV" see in my list but i can see all this "OPTIONSVerbHandler"

Comment: No brother... applicationhost.config this file is totally empty... i pasted you code in it... and retsrated server.... but same error...

Comment: Ensure you removed WebDAV module as provided in my answer. This should do it for you.

Comment: now it gives error. http://surveys.odalternatives.com/admin/access/signin

This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock

Comment: I did everything... "overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy " problem is gone... but "405 Method Not Allowed" is still there... please guide..

Comment: @AsadAliKhan https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Comment: Still Same error... I dont know where i m going wrong... you can view things at URL surveys.odalternatives.com/admin/access/signin

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE

Comment: i finally solve this.... I guess the issue was in MY URL - api/login which is called in POST... i changes that URL with api/login/checklogin.php and executed POST request.... it works.......

SUPER THANKS TO LIN for his guidance and 
http://stackoverflow.com always gives you the best.... THANKS ALL..

Comment: @AsadAliKhan I thought it could be at last that kind of error. The Setup before was necessary too. Glad to help ya.