# 405 Method Not Allowed Web API 2

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I've been through just about every article I can find, on SO and more. I've made changes to the `Web.config` to meet the answers as they all seem to point to removing the `WebDAV` module and handler.

However, I'm still getting the error:

> 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.

**NOTE:** this was originally just an MVC 4 project. I've added artifacts to support Web API. Seems like it's possible I may have missed something.

**NOTE:** the `GET` calls are working just fine from Angular.

## Web API Route Config

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default API",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get", id = RouteParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"[\da-z-]{36}" });

configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Default API with Action",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Get" });

var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
formatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

## Web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
</modules>
<handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

## `PUT` API Entry

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromBody] EditUserViewModel viewModel)
```

## Client Side

```
vm.model.$update(function () {
    $state.go(userStates.app);
});
```

Is it possible it's falling into the second route configuration? If so, how can I verify what route configuration .NET is trying to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)

Comment: I would create a Web.API app from scratch, recreate the problem and see if you can reproduce. It looks like you have done the correct webDAV config modifications. Like you said it's hard to tell if converting this from an mvc app caused some unseen pipeline issue.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but won't those routes both match, meaning that the first route will get hit?  Is it possible that the first route that matches only supports GET?

Comment: @BrendanGreen I was wondering the same thing, but it appears that's not the case. I'm not getting the error related to multiple matches. I got that after adding a new one and that error is very explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end it appears to be the fact that I was trying to complicate the routing table. I ended up rolling it back to this:

```
configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Do take note to the fact that I added `configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` as well.

After those two changes all is working well believe it or not. The `Web.config` looks like this:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"/>
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0"
       path="*."
       verb="*"
       type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
       preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"
       responseBufferLimit="0" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well and found that I had to do a little bit more.  Give this a try:

```
 <handlers>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <!-- Fix Microsofts propensity to interfere with requests -->
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" />
  <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" />
  <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
  <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <!-- IISFIX: Now that we're ripped out everything related to ASP.net, put them back correctly.-->
  <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.ashx" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.ashx" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated-4.0" path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.ashx" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.ashx" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="SimpleHandlerFactory-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.ashx" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <!--IISFIX: WebDAV is also buggy, and interferes with client requests-->
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
</handlers>
```