# Why doesn't this Web API route support the Delete HTTP method?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I have a Web API controller, `ClientController`, on which I have a method, `ResetAllProgress`. I would like to map the `DELETE` HTTP verb on the path `api/client/progress` to this method.

I am using [`AttributeRouting`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting/) for this purpose because I am stuck using Web API 1. Thus I have added an attribute to my method: `[DELETE("api/client/progress", ControllerPrecedence = 1)]`

I have paused my application during startup and observed that a corresponding route exists in the `Routes` collection. Below is a JSON serialization of the relevant parts of the `IHttpRoute` object:

```
{
    Constraints: {
        inboundHttpMethod: {
            AllowedMethods: ["DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
        }
    },
    DataTokens: {
        httpMethods: ["DELETE", "OPTIONS"]
    }
    Defaults: {
        controller: ClientController,
        action: ResetAllProgress
    },
    RouteTemplate: "/api/client/progress",
    Url: "api/client/progress"
}
```

However, when I try to initiate a `DELETE` call to `api/client/progress`, I receive a **405 Method Not Allowed**:

> {
>     "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'DELETE'."
>   }

If I adorn the `ResetAllProgress` method with an attribute, `[AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]`, then calls to `api/client/*` succeed. Presumably another route mapper picks up that attribute if it is present but I want to route it specifically to `api/client/progress`. I tried adding `[NonAction]` to counteract this, but then the route isn't registered at all.

However, when I issue a `POST` method to `api/client/progress`, I get an exception:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request:
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage Post(MyCompany.Models.ViewModel.ClientViewModel) on type MyCompany.Api.ClientController
>
> **System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage ResetAllProgress() on type MyCompany.Api.ClientController**
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage ChangePassword(MyCompany.Models.ViewModel.ChangePasswordModel) on type MyCompany.Api.ClientController
>
> Void SetDemo(MyCompany.Api.DemoViewModel) on type MyCompany.Api.ClientController

The other methods in that exception are *not* mapped to the `api/client/progress` route - or shouldn't be... I'm completely out of ideas, what can I do to figure this out?

Comment: Have you decorated the method with the [HttpDelete] attribute?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz thank you for the suggestion, however this has the same effect as `[AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]` - that is to say, it registers the Delete method for `api/client`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I don't think it's a server issue with accepting the Delete method - after all, if I use the attribute in my previous comment the site can accept it... Just for the wrong route!

Comment: I "fixed" my issue by replacing the `DELETE` attribute with a `POST` to `api/client/deleteprogress`... pragmatic at best