# Invalid PUT method from Webforms to Web API 2 (Azure)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API in my Azure server and I'm making calls from an ASP.NET Webforms website.

I seem to be able to perform GET with no trouble. Now for the PUT, it's giving me this error:

> The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid
>   method (HTTP verb) is being used

I was not able to DELETE either. I see some other topics where people disable some WebDav and stuff on their IIS servers and it works. But on Azure?

Below my code for the PUT:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/People/" + id).Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var yourcustomobjects = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<People>().Result;

    Uri peopleUrl = response.Headers.Location;

    yourcustomobjects.name= "Bob"; 
    response = await client.PutAsJsonAsync(peopleUrl, yourcustomobjects);
    tbDebug.Text += await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Do you have the web.config from the azure?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Comment: I assume you want the web.config from the API? And this section?:


<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Trying to understand how I make this more read-able I'm sorry

Comment: Ian, for your link, it requires to edit the file:
%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config

Azure doesn't seem to give me access to that.

Answer (score -1):

Alright I grew tired of trying to fix this issue by enabling PUT.

So what I did, was I wrote a GET that makes the needed change in the database.

Cheers