# Why is DELETE $.ajax call not caught by my controller?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to delete an entity using AJAX. In my controller method I have:

```
[HttpDelete]
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    //Deletion logic
    return Content("OK");
}
```

In the view I was making an AJAX call as follows:

```
$('#delete').click(function () {
    if (confirm('Delete?')) {
        var $link = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function (result) {
                $link.parent().remove();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

AJAX link is being built as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete?", "Delete", new { id = Model.Id }, new { id = "delete", @class = "delete-link" })
```

The `Delete` action is not getting the request from the link, but if I access through the direct URL it actually works. Also, if I delete the `type: 'DELETE',` line leaving it unspecified and replace the Controller Action line `[HttpDelete]` with `[HttpGet]` it works too.

My point is given it's a `DELETE` method I wouldn't want to handle it as a `GET` request but I can't figure out if I'm missing something else.

I would love if any of you guys could help me out to understand why the controller action `Delete(int id)` is not catching the requests coming from the AJAX Link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the value of this.href, it should match controller route.

Comment: @kostbone I've just added the way href is being generated. The value of it is an absolute Url as localhost/{Controller}/{Action}/X where X is an int.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm using MVC5 and for what I see [FromUri] is not available.

Comment: You're right, my mistake, that's from WebAPI

Comment: @CristiPufu I have many other [HttpDelete] calls in the application that work fine without Ajax. This however, is not. So, for me it's not IIS. I already tried Heinz's suggestion thou and didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that IIS does not allow PUT and DELETE (see [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8))

Check your handlers in your `Web.config`

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
           <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
           <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This change did the trick for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me. 404. The only way so far I've found for it to work is decorate Controller action as [HttpGet] and deleting type line from Ajax call.

Comment: How do your `handlers` section look like in your Web.config?

Comment: You were right about IIS. I did what @CristiPufu suggested and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`IIS` is blocking your `[HttpDelete]` method.

Add this in your `web.config`

```cs
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks. You were right indeed.