# Web API with OWIN, Preflight request returns OK but actual request returns 405. PUT, DELETE not allowed

Tags: asp.net, api, web-config, owin

Really confused with this error.

I am using Web Api and OAuth for user authentication. The first request to the site is a user register POST request which executes correctly.
The second request I send is the PUT request with user credentials to activate user, for which the preflight request returns `OK` but the actual PUT request returns `405` Method not Allowed and No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present error.

Everything works fine before hosting. This error occurs only in hosted API. I also checked the hosted client with `localhost:portNo/api` (i.e. ran api in local host and accessed it from hosted client app) and it works fine. Error occurs only in hosted application.

Preflight request is as follows:
    `Request URL: api.oorvalam.com/user/activate
    Request Method:OPTIONS
    Status Code:200 OK`

The preflight response is as follows:

    `Accept:/
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ta;q=0.6
    Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type, userlanguage
    Access-Control-Request-Method:PUT
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Connection:keep-alive
    Host:api.oorvalam.com
    Origin:http://web.oorvalam.com
    Pragma:no-cache
    Referer:web.oorvalam.com/setPassword`


The actual request:
    `Request URL:api.oorvalam.com/user/activate
    Request Method:PUT
    Status Code:405 Method Not Allowed`


The actual response is as follows:
    `Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
    Cache-Control:private
    Content-Length:5293
    Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
    Date:Mon, 19 Sep 2016 13:30:09 GMT
    Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
    X-Powered-By-Plesk:PleskWin`



FYI: The client is made with angular. Also removed some links http as stackoverflow isn't allowing me to.


Please let me know if there is anything I missed regarding CORS. And elaborate on why it is working in local and not working in Hosted api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot I found out that this was an error related to the Configuration in web.config.
 The answer is similar to this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722942/5003227
My final `<web.server>` in web.config is as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"></asp>
```

PUT, DELETE was not allowed until I added this configuration.