# IIS ASP WebApi Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, webdav, http-status-code-405

on one pc i got the problem that asp web api doesn't accept http verbs like `PUT` and `DELETE`.

I removed webdav via webconfig

and my config looks liek this

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />

      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

I IIS i deactivated filtering options of webdav for the given site

When I add

```
<add name="WebDAV" path="*" verb="*" modules="WebDAVModule"
     resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
```

then the methods are allowed but from there on i can't attach a debugger to this api site with the "Method not allowed" eror.

[image]

Controller Method is defined like this:

```
[HttpDelete]
[Authorize]
[Route("api/projects/{id:guid}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete(Guid id)
{
```

can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Show the controllers that give you that error when called. you may be missing a Http*Verb attribute on the action

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Comment: And take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10907343/5233410