# 404 Rejected-By-UrlScan Delete Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-403, http-delete

On my Web API I have a few `[HttpGet]` functions that work perfectly, but the one that is `[HttpDelete]` (on the same Controller) doesn't work, it returns 404 error.

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("DeleteUser/{ID}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        _UserRepository.Delete(id);
    }
}
```

On the web.config I have the `verb` set to `*`:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

The AJAX call:

```
deleteUser = function (id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../API/Users/DeleteUser/" + id,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function () {
            callback;
        }
    });
}
```

The error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   Detailed Error Information
>   Module    IIS Web Core Notification   MapRequestHandler Handler   StaticFile
>
> Error Code    0x80070002
>
> Requested
>   URL   https://www.example.com:443/Rejected-By-UrlScan?~/API/Users/DeleteUser/155
>
> Physical Path d:\wr\mySite\example.com\Rejected-By-UrlScan 
>   Logon Method  Anonymous Logon User    Anonymous

All the calls are authenticated with OWIN Authentication and a bearer token.

An example of a working call on the same page:

```
getUsers = function (callback) {
    $.get("../../API/Users/GetUsers/", callback);
}
```

What can causes it?

Comment: Can you include more of the controller like its definition and if it has any attributes on it. Also show the raw response when sending a request that fails.

Comment: Are you authenticated when sending the request? Noticing controller is tagged with `[Authorize]` attribute

Comment: Show one of the calls that do work in production

Comment: @Nkosi Please see my edited question.

Comment: Depending on your IIS version your should take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Comment: The IIS version is 7.5, I saw this question and tried everything suggested there but with no success, the website is on a shared server so it's a little bit difficult to access it.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45126105/1689226), there may be an extension ([UrlScan](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan)) configured in IIS to block DELETE requests. You can check your IIS for this extension.

Comment: In my case this worked. I just uninstalled "Microsoft UrlScan Filter" using Windows Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the verbs manually

```xml
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" 
           path="*." 
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT" 
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Also check to make sure

- That you are calling the correct path.
- you do not have a folder that matches the intended route

---

Also, your route template place holder needs to match the action parameter name

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController {

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("DeleteUser/{id:int}")] //Matches DELETE {root}/Users/DeleteUser/5
    [AcceptVerbs("DELETE")]
    public IHttpActionResult Delete(int id) {
        //TODO: check if {id} exists and if not, then return NotFound()
        _UserRepository.Delete(id);
        return Ok();
    }

    //...other members
}
```

Comment: Depending on your IIS version your should take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Comment: The IIS version is 7.5, I saw this question and tried everything suggested there but with no success, the website is on a shared server so it's a little bit difficult to access it.