# Web API 404 error Delete request

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that worked perfectly on development with all kind of HTTP requests (on the same controller), once I moved it to production (shared server, I don't even have access to it) the `DELETE` requests stopped working (the others are working fine), I get a 404 error:

> Requested
>   URL   https://www.example.com:443/**Rejected-By-UrlScan~**/API/Users/DeleteUser/1
>
> Physical Path d:\xx\yy\example.com\Rejected-By-UrlScan
>
> Logon Method   Anonymous
>
> Logon User Anonymous

This is (a part of) the web.config:

```
 <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

The Delete Action:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("DeleteUser/{id:int}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        _UsersRepository.Delete(id);
    }
```

And the AJAX call:

```
deleteUser = function (id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../API/Users/DeleteUser/" + id,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function () {
            callback;
        }
    });
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //create json formatter and remove all others
        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.FormUrlEncodedFormatter);
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
    }
```

An example of a working call on the same Controller:

```
getUsers = function (callback) {
    $.get("../API/Users/GetUsers/", callback);
}
```

And the Action:

```
[Route("GetUsers")]
public IEnumerable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return _UsersRepository.GetUsers();
}
```

Comment: Why did you access as anonymous though `UsersController` has `[Authorize]`? It's not strongly related to 404 issue but strange.

Comment: @Youngjae I'm using a `bearer token` and I see it set up properly in my headers, not sure why it has "anonymous".. I think the 404 error occurs because of the `Rejected-By-UrlScan` that causes the url to change but I don't know what to do about it, would you know?

Comment: I have no idea, but it would be good to post your `WebApiConfig.cs` or `Startup.cs` also.

Comment: @Youngjae I posted it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to got it to work so I changed the type of the request from `DELETE` to `POST` and it works perfectly:

```
[Authorize]
[RoutePrefix("Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
    {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DeleteUser/{id:int}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        _UsersRepository.Delete(id);
    }

deleteUser = function (id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../API/Users/DeleteUser/" + id,
        type: "POST",
        success: function () {
            callback;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: That doesn't actually answer the question but completely ignores it.

Answer (score 5):

In your IIS do you have the URLScan extension configured ?

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/urlscan

> UrlScan is a security tool that **restricts the types of HTTP requests** that IIS will process.

The "Rejected-By-UrlScan" in your URL suggests that the extension may be configured to reject "Delete" requests.

You can ask your Administrator of the Server hosting the IIS about whether Delete requests are configured to be allowed in the IIS.

Comment: In my case this worked. I just uninstalled "Microsoft UrlScan Filter" using Windows Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is wrong in the JS snippet. It should be

```
deleteUser = function (id, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "[Application_Path]/Users/DeleteUser/" + id,
        type: "DELETE",
        success: function () {
            callback;
        }
    });
}

[RoutePrefix("Users")] overrides the default routing, so there should be no "API" in the URL.
```

You should remove the [Application_Path] and put your virtual directory name or use the `@Url.Action`

Comment: Please post the code for other calls if it calls the same action and same controller.

Comment: You should not use the "../../" in a URL, make your URL either relative to the current page or absolute. I guess it maybe working with the get users as you have it 2 levels so, it skips the API word, however in the delete user, there is only one "../" so it still access the URL wit API in it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, they both have one `../`

Comment: In this case, inspect the traffic in your browser and check what is the FULL URL that is being called in both cases. You can check that in Dev and Production

Comment: I see that the url of the `DELETE` requests is wrong because of the `Rejected-By-UrlScan~`

Comment: Why is there a Rejected-By-UrlScan~ in the URL? do you have any extension in the browser or you are using a tool or something?

Comment: I don't know. this is what _I'm_ asking.