# DELETE verb not working in iis 10

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, cors, iis-10, http-delete

DELETE method is showing the below error in IIS 10

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

All other methods like POST and GET are working fine. 
Also DELETE was working fine in iis express at the time of development.
I had enabled cors for all requests in WebApiConfig class

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

my webconfig looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!--   For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301879   --> <configuration>   <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />   </configSections>   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection" connectionString="server=maclinkserver\mssql_dev;uid=sa;password=123;database=bisellsERP" />   </connectionStrings>   <appSettings></appSettings>   <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>   </system.web>   <system.webServer>

    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />   </system.webServer>   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>   </runtime>   <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>   </entityFramework>   <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>   </system.codedom> </configuration>
```

Tried many things from this question
[ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)
But not yet solved.

Comment: Can you check in your browser whether the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header exists in the response headers. First time the browsers will make OPTIONS preflight request asking the server that the origin and the methods are allowed. More info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Another thing that you cloud try is to set `[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]` attribute on the API controller and use `config.EnableCors();` only

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution from somewhere else.
I just uninstalled WEBDAV feature from iis

just follow

> Control Panel -> Uninstall Program -> Turn Windows features on or off
>   -> IIS -> World Wide Web Services -> Common HTTP feature -> WebDAV Publishing

Answer (score 3):

By default `DELETE` verb is disabled in IIS local, you need to enable it by editing your

> applicationhost.config

```
<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Simply add  `DELETE` in the list of verbs enabled.

Comment: Gaur How to access applicationhost.config ? Sorry i am not a deployment pro

Comment: The file is located at C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config , please run notepad as administrator to edit the file

Comment: i found the file . but no such `<add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />` is found

Comment: in which parent node i should add this

Comment: <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0" 
           path="*." 
           verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,DELETE,PUT" 
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

Comment: Also add the same in the %userprofile%\documents\IISExpress\config” folder's config as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156248/discussion-between-ipsit-gaur-and-nithin-chandran).

Answer (score 2):

Ipsit Gaur's answer helped, but the uninstall procedure on windows 2019 is different:

Open the Server Manager and select "Manage", "Remove Roles and Features", jump to the "Server Roles" section and uncheck the following option:

Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Common HTTP Features > WebDAV Publishing

Select "Next" until you can select "Remove" on the Confirmation section. You may need to restart the server for the change to take effect.

Here is the [source](https://docs.inedo.com/docs/various/iis/disabling-webdav#:%7E:text=Windows%20Desktop%20Editions&text=Select%20the%20Turn%20Windows%20features,the%20change%20to%20take%20effect).