# WEB API error-404 - "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-put

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: GET,POST
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcUHJvamVjdHNcZG90TmV0XFdlYkFQSVxBZFNlcnZpY2VcQWRTZXJ2aWNlXGFwaVxpbXByZXNzaW9uXDE1?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 06 May 2014 14:10:35 GMT
Content-Length: 72

{"message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'."}
```

I want to generate PUT and DELETE request using POSTMAN but I got following message from POSTMAN.

Even I have implemented all the suggestions given by ASP.NET site.

Below is Web API c# code:

```
 // PUT: api/Students/5
    [HttpPut]
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutStudent(decimal Enrollment_no, Student student)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (Enrollment_no != student.Enrollment_no)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!StudentExists(Enrollment_no))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Nothing has worked as I'm still getting a 405 response when trying to issue a "PUT" command against my Web API project.

Comment: you must be using any other verb rather than "PUT", check your code.

Comment: You'll need to show us your Web API controller (or at least what methods you've defined)

Comment: Add your controller and routing code.

Comment: In order to use PUT your action method must have the attribute `[HttpPut]`.

Comment: Response shows allowed HTTP verbs : `Allow: GET,POST`

Comment: @PeterB I have mentioned it in my c# code.You can check it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)

Answer (score 0):

Your back end api is only allowing GET and POST requests(see response header Allow ), hence to generate PUT/DELETE request API should add support for the same.

Comment: How to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this by modifying `web.config` of your ASP.NET Web API. Try to find the following line:
`<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`

Replace it with:
`<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8) for more information.

Comment: Did you also try to remove `WebDAVModule`?