# IIS blocks HEAD method, returns 405 while All Verbs are allowed

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api2

I'm creating an app. I have a method that pings my API to see if it's online.
This is done with a HEAD call.

However, HEAD seems to be blocked, I get a 405 response.
I've followed suggestions here: [ASP.NET Web API - PUT & DELETE Verbs Not Allowed - IIS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8)
but Verbs is set to ALL.

We've also checked

- SSL certificate
- CORS
- Cookies
- Access tokens
- Strict-Transport-Security

and none of those are the cause.

What else can I do? The API is a Web API 2.0 application, we're using IIS 10

**Update 20-11-2021**

Issue is still not resolved. We've resorted to GET requests.
I hope someday someone will stand up who can give us clear instructions for IIS 10, including not only the troubleshooting steps to take but also what to look for in the output.

Comment: Enable FRT to see what gives you 405, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: command cause of the issue is multiple handlers are defined for the same verb/method, and one of the handlers is blocking the expected handler from processing the request. you could try to add this code in web.config file:`<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>`

Comment: refer this link for more deatil:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Comment: Issue is not resolved yet, your comments are either for old version of IIS, or they suggest something we've already tried or it points to troubleshooting that doesn't tell me what to look for in the output.