# Call Back Request With Form data to React Application hosted on IIS Server

Tags: reactjs, react-router, web-hosting, httphandler, iis-10

If any one can help me with one of the issue with IIS hosting.

I have a react application hosted in IIS 10. In one of the workflow there is call back from external server to my react application along with some data. This call back request is a HTTP Post request from Server. So when this request hits IIS (hosting React App), server is not able to determine how to process this request and route this request to React router and gives 405 error ( HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed).

[image]

I have already tried with removing WebDAV. Also tried with specifically adding HTTP Post in Request Filtering section of IIS but is also not working.

**PS**: The same call back works perfectly when change hosting from IIS to Firebase. But due to some limitations need to keep using IIS as hosting server.
Let me know if anyone has faced such issue and how did you resolved it.

Comment: You can refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906411/asp-net-web-api-put-delete-verbs-not-allowed-iis-8

Comment: Thanks @TheobaldDu I did tried that post, it was not working for me. Nevertheless I found the solution posting it as an answer